# How to use svg from the folder path in appendchild method javascript or reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to reactjs and i stuck with appending svg element to the div element.

What is that i want to implement?
I have a div element created dynamically like below.

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.element = document.createElement('div');
}
```

I have a svg imported to the component like below
import SvgName from '../svg/name.svg';

and want to append this SvgName to the div element created dynamically in the above constructor.

What i have tried....is below,

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.element = document.createElement('div');
      const svg = document.createElement('svg');
      this.element.appendChild(svg);
}
```

The above will append a svg element however it doesnt add the svg that i want (the one imported).

How can i achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `svg` element in your example is a react component, so it can be rendered inside DOM elements with `ReactDOM.render`, like that:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.render(<SvgComponent />, this.element);
}
```

The `ReactDOM.render` call does not necessarily have to be in the `componentDidMount` handler, you can use it in whatever part of the lifecycle of the component you feel like, as long as `this.element` is an initialized DOM element.

Answer (score 4):

From the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

> One way to add SVG files was described in the section above. You can
>   also import SVGs directly as React components. You can use either of
>   the two approaches. In your code it would look like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
    <Logo />
  </div>
);
```

This will load the svg as component and you can use it.

Full Read [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create element dynamically I would suggest you to use your Component's state. In react it is not good practice to operate with DOM directly like you do. So your code should looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import {ReactComponent as SvgName} from '../svg/name.svg'

class SomeClass extends React.Component {
  state = {
    renderImage: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(someConditionMets) {
       this.setState({renderImage: true});
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.renderImage) return <div><SvgName /></div>;

    return null;
  }
}

export default SomeClass;
```

Or if you want your div to render every time you can change render method to:

```
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.renderImage && <SvgName />}</div>
  }
```