# React : Import dynamic SVG

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to import a different set of SVG icons based on my Branding variable.
I try something like this :

```
import { BRANDING } from 'BrandingBuilder';
import {`${BRANDING}-icons.svg`};
```

But I know React didn't support to import a {variable}. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569628/2630817

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files):

> You can
>   also import SVGs directly as React components. You can use either of
>   the two approaches. In your code it would look like this:

```
import { BRANDING } from 'BrandingBuilder';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from `${BRANDING}-icons.svg`;
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
    <Logo />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I don't want to kow how to import SVG, I'm using svg-sprite-loader. I want to know If I can import DIFFERENT SVG based on a ENV variable ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is on the import with a variable.

Comment: Try to console.log the variable and make sure it comes back as a string

Comment: @Dmitriy I haven't seen a usage like this before. Could you please share your working online demo?

Comment: @ziLk sure, here's a sandbox with this implementation https://codesandbox.io/s/3ywqo2x1r1

You need react-scripts@2.0.0 or higher

Comment: I was wondering `${BRANDING} part of the code. I have never seen like this before. Please share your working code which has a dynamic path like in your answer.

Comment: ${BRANDING} is a variable using Javascript template strings, in this case the variable was a string to match the SVG path