# How can I include this svg in a react component ?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480.5 117.9"><style>.st0{fill:#222426}.st1{fill:#bcbbbb}.st2{fill:#f48024}</style><path class="st0" d="M123.7 67.3l-4.8-.4c-3.7-.3-5.2-1.8-5.2-4.3 0-3 2.3-4.9 6.6-4.9 3.1 0 5.8.7 7.9 2.4l2.8-2.8c-2.7-2.2-6.4-3.2-10.7-3.2-6.3 0-10.9 3.3-10.9 8.7 0 4.9 3.1 7.5 8.9 8l4.9.4c3.4.3 4.9 1.7 4.9 4.3 0 3.5-3 5.2-7.9 5.2-3.7 0-6.9-1-9.2-3.4l-2.9 2.9c3.3 3.1 7.2 4.3 12.2 4.3 7.2 0 12.1-3.3 12.1-9 .1-5.8-3.5-7.7-8.7-8.2zm37.2-13.4c-4.8 0-7.8.9-10.4 4.3l2.8 2.8c1.7-2.5 3.7-3.4 7.5-3.4 5.4 0 7.6 2.2 7.6 6.5V67h-8.9c-6.6 0-10.2 3.4-10.2 8.6 0 2.4.8 4.6 2.2 6 1.9 1.9 4.3 2.7 8.4 2.7 4 0 6.1-.8 8.6-3.2V84h4.3V63.8c-.1-6.4-4-9.9-11.9-9.9zm7.5 19.6c0 2.5-.5 4.2-1.5 5.1-1.9 1.8-4.1 2-6.6 2-4.7 0-6.8-1.6-6.8-5.1 0-3.4 2.2-5.2 6.6-5.2h8.3v3.2zm21.3-15.7c2.8 0 4.6.8 6.8 3.3l2.9-2.8c-3-3.3-5.6-4.3-9.7-4.3-7.5 0-13.1 5.1-13.1 15.2s5.7 15.2 13.1 15.2c4.1 0 6.7-1.1 9.8-4.4l-3-2.8c-2.2 2.5-4 3.4-6.8 3.4-2.9 0-5.3-1.1-6.9-3.4-1.4-1.9-1.9-4.2-1.9-8 0-3.7.5-6 1.9-8 1.6-2.3 4-3.4 6.9-3.4zm37.2-3.5h-5.4L208 67.4V41.1h-4.3V84h4.3V73.2l5.3-5.3 9.9 16.1h5.4l-12.3-19.1 10.6-10.6zm20.4-1.6c-4.6 0-7.6 1.8-9.5 3.8-2.8 2.9-3.5 6.4-3.5 12s.7 9.1 3.5 12c1.9 2 5 3.8 9.5 3.8 4.6 0 7.7-1.8 9.6-3.8 2.8-2.9 3.5-6.4 3.5-12s-.7-9.1-3.5-12c-1.9-2-5.1-3.8-9.6-3.8zm3.6 23.3c-.9.9-2.1 1.4-3.6 1.4s-2.7-.5-3.6-1.4c-1.6-1.6-1.8-4.3-1.8-7.5s.2-5.9 1.8-7.5c.9-.9 2-1.4 3.6-1.4 1.5 0 2.7.5 3.6 1.4 1.6 1.6 1.8 4.3 1.8 7.5s-.2 5.9-1.8 7.5zm30-22.9l-6.2 19.1-6.3-19.1h-8.1L271.7 84h6L289 53.1h-8.1zm21.3-.4c-8 0-13.5 5.7-13.5 15.8 0 12.5 7 15.8 14.3 15.8 5.6 0 8.6-1.7 11.7-4.9l-4.7-4.6c-2 2-3.6 2.9-7 2.9-4.3 0-6.8-2.9-6.8-6.9h19.3v-3.4c.1-8.4-4.8-14.7-13.3-14.7zm-5.9 12.9c.1-1.4.2-2.2.7-3.3.8-1.8 2.5-3.2 5.2-3.2 2.6 0 4.3 1.4 5.2 3.2.5 1.1.7 2 .7 3.3h-11.8zM327 56v-3h-7.5v31h7.7V65.4c0-3.9 2.6-5.7 5-5.7 1.9 0 2.9.6 4.1 1.8l5.8-5.8c-2.1-2.1-4.3-2.9-7.3-2.9-3.4-.1-6.3 1.5-7.8 3.2zm17.4-6.1V84h7.7V59.6h5.7v-5.9h-5.7v-3.4c0-1.8.9-2.8 2.7-2.8h3V41h-4.4c-6.2 0-9 4.5-9 8.9zm45.2 2.8c-4.6 0-7.6 1.8-9.5 3.8-2.8 2.9-3.5 6.4-3.5 12s.7 9.1 3.5 12c1.9 2 5 3.8 9.5 3.8 4.6 0 7.7-1.8 9.6-3.8 2.8-2.9 3.5-6.4 3.5-12s-.7-9.1-3.5-12c-1.9-2-5.1-3.8-9.6-3.8zm3.6 23.3c-.9.9-2.1 1.4-3.6 1.4s-2.7-.5-3.6-1.4c-1.6-1.6-1.8-4.3-1.8-7.5s.2-5.9 1.8-7.5c.9-.9 2-1.4 3.6-1.4 1.5 0 2.7.5 3.6 1.4 1.6 1.6 1.8 4.3 1.8 7.5s-.2 5.9-1.8 7.5zm45.9-22.9l-5 19.1-6.3-19.1h-5.6l-6.3 19.1-5-19.1h-8.2l9.5 30.9h6.3l6.5-19.4 6.5 19.4h6.3l9.4-30.9h-8.1zm-69.9 21.6V41h-7.7v34.1c0 4.4 2.7 8.8 9 8.8h4.4v-6.5h-3c-1.9 0-2.7-.9-2.7-2.7zM144.5 59l4-4h-8.2v-9.8H136V76c0 4.4 2.5 8 7.6 8h3.1v-3.7h-2.3c-2.8 0-4-1.6-4-4.3V59h4.1z"/><path class="st1" d="M87.6 91.3v-22H95v29.3H29.1V69.3h7.3v22z"/><path class="st2" d="M44.5 67.3l35.9 7.5 1.5-7.2L46 60.1l-1.5 7.2zm4.7-17.2l33.2 15.5 3.1-6.6-33.2-15.6-3.1 6.7zm9.2-16.3l28.2 23.4 4.7-5.6-28.2-23.4-4.7 5.6zm18.2-17.3l-5.9 4.4 21.9 29.4 5.9-4.4-21.9-29.4zM43.7 83.9h36.6v-7.3H43.7v7.3z"/></svg>
    );
```

When I try including this anywhere inside the react component , the path and fill attributes give error. Can someone please tell me how to include any svg component which has any kind of xml inside any react component ?

Comment: Try this playground - https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/playground/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use svg from the folder path in appendchild method javascript or reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569541/how-to-use-svg-from-the-folder-path-in-appendchild-method-javascript-or-reactjs)

Comment: @Justcode that question doesn't address the errors because of path or style or fill .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the trouble in your styles and `class`

JSX detect `{` as start of JS code and parse your `fill:#222426` as JS

`class` should be `className`

```
 const styles = '.st0{fill:#222426};.st1{fill:#bcbbbb};.st2{fill:#f48024};';

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 480.5 117.9">
        <style>{styles}</style>
        <path className="st0" d="M123.7 67.3l-4.8-.4c-3.7-.3-5.2-1.8-5.2-4.3 0-3 2.3-4.9 6.6-4.9 3.1 0 5.8.7 7.9 2.4l2.8-2.8c-2.7-2.2-6.4-3.2-10.7-3.2-6.3 0-10.9 3.3-10.9 8.7 0 4.9 3.1 7.5 8.9 8l4.9.4c3.4.3 4.9 1.7 4.9 4.3 0 3.5-3 5.2-7.9 5.2-3.7 0-6.9-1-9.2-3.4l-2.9 2.9c3.3 3.1 7.2 4.3 12.2 4.3 7.2 0 12.1-3.3 12.1-9 .1-5.8-3.5-7.7-8.7-8.2zm37.2-13.4c-4.8 0-7.8.9-10.4 4.3l2.8 2.8c1.7-2.5 3.7-3.4 7.5-3.4 5.4 0 7.6 2.2 7.6 6.5V67h-8.9c-6.6 0-10.2 3.4-10.2 8.6 0 2.4.8 4.6 2.2 6 1.9 1.9 4.3 2.7 8.4 2.7 4 0 6.1-.8 8.6-3.2V84h4.3V63.8c-.1-6.4-4-9.9-11.9-9.9zm7.5 19.6c0 2.5-.5 4.2-1.5 5.1-1.9 1.8-4.1 2-6.6 2-4.7 0-6.8-1.6-6.8-5.1 0-3.4 2.2-5.2 6.6-5.2h8.3v3.2zm21.3-15.7c2.8 0 4.6.8 6.8 3.3l2.9-2.8c-3-3.3-5.6-4.3-9.7-4.3-7.5 0-13.1 5.1-13.1 15.2s5.7 15.2 13.1 15.2c4.1 0 6.7-1.1 9.8-4.4l-3-2.8c-2.2 2.5-4 3.4-6.8 3.4-2.9 0-5.3-1.1-6.9-3.4-1.4-1.9-1.9-4.2-1.9-8 0-3.7.5-6 1.9-8 1.6-2.3 4-3.4 6.9-3.4zm37.2-3.5h-5.4L208 67.4V41.1h-4.3V84h4.3V73.2l5.3-5.3 9.9 16.1h5.4l-12.3-19.1 10.6-10.6zm20.4-1.6c-4.6 0-7.6 1.8-9.5 3.8-2.8 2.9-3.5 6.4-3.5 12s.7 9.1 3.5 12c1.9 2 5 3.8 9.5 3.8 4.6 0 7.7-1.8 9.6-3.8 2.8-2.9 3.5-6.4 3.5-12s-.7-9.1-3.5-12c-1.9-2-5.1-3.8-9.6-3.8zm3.6 23.3c-.9.9-2.1 1.4-3.6 1.4s-2.7-.5-3.6-1.4c-1.6-1.6-1.8-4.3-1.8-7.5s.2-5.9 1.8-7.5c.9-.9 2-1.4 3.6-1.4 1.5 0 2.7.5 3.6 1.4 1.6 1.6 1.8 4.3 1.8 7.5s-.2 5.9-1.8 7.5zm30-22.9l-6.2 19.1-6.3-19.1h-8.1L271.7 84h6L289 53.1h-8.1zm21.3-.4c-8 0-13.5 5.7-13.5 15.8 0 12.5 7 15.8 14.3 15.8 5.6 0 8.6-1.7 11.7-4.9l-4.7-4.6c-2 2-3.6 2.9-7 2.9-4.3 0-6.8-2.9-6.8-6.9h19.3v-3.4c.1-8.4-4.8-14.7-13.3-14.7zm-5.9 12.9c.1-1.4.2-2.2.7-3.3.8-1.8 2.5-3.2 5.2-3.2 2.6 0 4.3 1.4 5.2 3.2.5 1.1.7 2 .7 3.3h-11.8zM327 56v-3h-7.5v31h7.7V65.4c0-3.9 2.6-5.7 5-5.7 1.9 0 2.9.6 4.1 1.8l5.8-5.8c-2.1-2.1-4.3-2.9-7.3-2.9-3.4-.1-6.3 1.5-7.8 3.2zm17.4-6.1V84h7.7V59.6h5.7v-5.9h-5.7v-3.4c0-1.8.9-2.8 2.7-2.8h3V41h-4.4c-6.2 0-9 4.5-9 8.9zm45.2 2.8c-4.6 0-7.6 1.8-9.5 3.8-2.8 2.9-3.5 6.4-3.5 12s.7 9.1 3.5 12c1.9 2 5 3.8 9.5 3.8 4.6 0 7.7-1.8 9.6-3.8 2.8-2.9 3.5-6.4 3.5-12s-.7-9.1-3.5-12c-1.9-2-5.1-3.8-9.6-3.8zm3.6 23.3c-.9.9-2.1 1.4-3.6 1.4s-2.7-.5-3.6-1.4c-1.6-1.6-1.8-4.3-1.8-7.5s.2-5.9 1.8-7.5c.9-.9 2-1.4 3.6-1.4 1.5 0 2.7.5 3.6 1.4 1.6 1.6 1.8 4.3 1.8 7.5s-.2 5.9-1.8 7.5zm45.9-22.9l-5 19.1-6.3-19.1h-5.6l-6.3 19.1-5-19.1h-8.2l9.5 30.9h6.3l6.5-19.4 6.5 19.4h6.3l9.4-30.9h-8.1zm-69.9 21.6V41h-7.7v34.1c0 4.4 2.7 8.8 9 8.8h4.4v-6.5h-3c-1.9 0-2.7-.9-2.7-2.7zM144.5 59l4-4h-8.2v-9.8H136V76c0 4.4 2.5 8 7.6 8h3.1v-3.7h-2.3c-2.8 0-4-1.6-4-4.3V59h4.1z"/>
        <path className="st1" d="M87.6 91.3v-22H95v29.3H29.1V69.3h7.3v22z"/>
        <path className="st2" d="M44.5 67.3l35.9 7.5 1.5-7.2L46 60.1l-1.5 7.2zm4.7-17.2l33.2 15.5 3.1-6.6-33.2-15.6-3.1 6.7zm9.2-16.3l28.2 23.4 4.7-5.6-28.2-23.4-4.7 5.6zm18.2-17.3l-5.9 4.4 21.9 29.4 5.9-4.4-21.9-29.4zM43.7 83.9h36.6v-7.3H43.7v7.3z"/>
    </svg>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f9we6vm1/1/

Comment: how to retain the color of that svg ?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with those colors? Change them dynamically?

Comment: it doesn't display the colors other than black and white , i want to retain the colors of the svg (which shows whne I open it in browser directly )

Comment: @Nateshbhat, sure, I added extra semicolons, so CSS wasn't valid :) Check the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Put this text in Notepad file and save it with `.svg` extension `img.svg`
then add this file to your project and use `<img src={'path/img.svg'} />`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the style tag.

`<style type="text/css" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "\n\t.st0{fill: #222426}\n\t.st1{fill: #bcbbbb}\n\t.st2{fill: #f48024}\n" }} />`

Formatting the code like this would solve the issue.

You can also save the contents in an .svg file and import it into the src of an `<img>` tag